# Vue Composition API - Using computed which transforms data in setup()?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-composition-api

We're currently converting from boilerplate VUE 2 to Composition API, and i'm struggling to understand how to rewrite our current **computed** to support Composition API :

```
setup() {
    const store = useStore<StoreState>();
    // Question : how do i implement the infoFields into the setup ? 
    // const contactSingle = computed(() => store.state.contacts.contactSingle);
    return { contactSingle };
  },
computed: {
    ...mapGetters("contacts", ["getContact"]),
    infoFields(): any {
      return [
        {
          value: (this as any).getContact.customer.firstName,
          label: "Fornavn",
        },
        {
          value: (this as any).getContact.customer.lastName,
          label: "Etternavn",
        },
        ...
        ...
        ];
    },


 <v-row>
  <v-col class="pt-0" v-for="(item, i) in infoFields" :key="i + '-field'" cols="12" xs="12" sm="6" md="6" lg="4">
    <BaseSheetField :value="item.value" :label="item.label" />
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Comment: The code is not equivalent. If you have a getter, use a getter. `data` becomes `ref` or `reactive`. By using a computed inside `data` you've lost reactivity. Is this intentional?

Comment: Probably should be reactive yes.. My normal approach would be using a clean getter, populate the form with data _without_ using the iteration. 
But.. since the tech-lead want it this way, i'm trying to find a way to do this and keep the reactivtiness within.. any ideas @EstusFlask ?

Comment: It's like the answer says, just use a computed. Would be the same in Vue 2 to preserve reactivity, with different syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what exactly is the problem, but I think using `store.getters` in computed should work:

```
const infoFields = computed(() => {
    return [
        {
          value: store.getters["contacts/getContact"].customer.firstName,
          label: "Fornavn",
        },
        {
          value: store.getters["contacts/getContact"].customer.lastName,
          label: "Etternavn",
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: This might be sufficent :) Will try this out Igor. (Have to check on the requirements for reactiveness though...)

Comment: it worked :) Thanks for great help and for spending time helping me out Igor Moraru and Estus Flask :)